# Iterate over JSON to dynamically create multiple JQuery Mobile Pages

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I'm learning JQuery mobile and to help me down the path I'm seeking an example problem solution.  I'd like to iterate over a JSON query to dynamically create multiple pages within a single HTML page (see multipage http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html).  Ideally, each page would have a forward and back button to advance/regress through the JQuery mobile pages.

UPDATE: What I have so far;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Get JSONP</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="target">
<script>
// best to put this code in an external .js file
var loadtwitter = function() {

  $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json' + '?q=jquery&callback=?', function(data) {
     $.each(data.results, function(index, value) {
       var o1 = "<div data-role='page' id='page" + index +"' data-title='Twitter Item " + index +"'>";
       var o2 = "<div data-role='header'><h1>Item " + index + "</h1></div>"; 
       var o3 = "<div data-role='content'><p>" + value.text + "</p>";
       var o4 = "<a href='#page" + (index - 1) + "' data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-icon='arrow-l'>Previous</a>";
       var o5 = "<a href='#page" + (index + 1) + "' data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-icon='arrow-r'>Next</a>";
       var o6 = "</div>";           
       var output = o1 + o2 + o3 + o4 + o5 + o6;  
       $('#target').append(output);
     });

    }); 
   $.mobile.changePage($("#page1"));
  };

  $(document).ready(loadtwitter);
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Cluther, I'm not clear on where exactly JSON fits into this. Perhaps you can include some examples of things you've tried so far or post the code that you do have. This will give us some context to form a starting point and help get you from point A to point B. For instance, are you wanting to populate an HTML template with data from a JSON response? Please add more clarity and details. Thanks!

Comment: Work plan - (a) work out how to achieve these multiple pages with a hard-coded js object, then (b) work out how to deliver a json-encoded version of such an object.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, as they helped move me forward.  However I'm still not quite there.  Please see the sample code below.  I can verify that I'm successfully calling the JSON object, and iterating over it to create multiple jQuery Mobile pages.  However I can't seem to get the browser to move to the first of the dynamic pages.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery mobile you shouldn't be relying on $(document).ready. you would be better off using the below pattern borrowed from the [jQuery docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html).

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
            loadtwitter();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```